# What does the -Odo suffix in Thrawn's name mean?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends

While reading Thrawn Ascendancy: Chaos Rising I noticed that sometimes Thrawn is referred to as **Mitth'raw'nuru** and sometimes as **Mitth'raw'nuruodo** the latter of which is also the traditional name he has in most appearances outside of the Ascendancy.

Now, I also remember Eli Vanto remarking (in Thrawn: Treason) that the third part of a chiss name has something to do with social status.

My question is now:

**Is it known what the *-odo* suffix to Thrawn's name means and if so what *does* it mean?**

Comment: Not sure if can be a proper anserw, but for now we still don't know where/when/why he get that last suffix. We can speculate the anserw lies in the following book(s)!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[Chiss names](https://io9.gizmodo.com/chiss-names-are-some-of-star-wars-coolest-bullshit-1844634626) are indeed complicated, being constructed from three parts. For the case of *Mitth’raw’nurodo*, the “Mitth” is the family name (like a surname for us), “raw” is his given name, and then “nuruodo” reflects his relationship to his family. Thrawn was not born into the Mitth family by blood, he was adopted into it, and so he was originally known as Kivu’raw’nuru, since his birth family was the Kivu.

Following his adoption into the Mitth his name changed to Mitth’raw’nuru, and he was known as such in his early military career. However, later the "nuru" termination seems to have changed to "nurodo" with no explanation. A Del Ray editor has [tweeted](https://twitter.com/DarthInternous/status/1302296639877656582):

> The "odo" has a currently unexplained special meaning, and is not part
> of his Mitth family name. So the scenes when his name ends in "uru"
> are before he's earned those 3 letters. As for what exactly those 3
> letters mean that's something Tim plans to explore. Stay tuned :)

That tweet was made on September 5th 2020, and as far as I know (though I'd love to be corrected!) the hidden meaning has not been revealed yet.

Comment: “Chiss fans like it Raw.”

Comment: Do we even know if Kivu’raw is even anyone of note, or is he just some married Chiss schmoe stuck in 9-5 job who’s created a whole exciting secret life of Rawter Mitty?

Answer (score 4):

The name change is adressed in a sequence of "Memories" in the recently released Thrawn Ascendancy: Lesser Evil. The least spoilery version is that it's an honorific given to Thrawn after an important victory and *to my understanding* for his overall skill and dedication to protecting the Chiss.

> The suffix was given to Thrawn by the Stybla family (with only 8 non-Styblas having received it before him in the past 5000 years) in accordance with the Mitth Patriarch Thooraki. It's meaning is that it designates the wearer as a "guardian or protector who had proved worthy of the most extraordinary respect", though that seems to not be common knowledge among Chiss. It was given to him for the flawless recovery of an important part of the Stybla's secret *Starflash* device and *to my understanding* also for his overall military achievements and dedication to protecting the Ascendancy.

Comment: Thank you for providing the final ingredient!